# MongoDB : count number of documents from multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb

I have multiple MongoDB collections, for example :

```
 1. First
 2. Second
 3. Third
```

I just want to count number of all records from collections :

For that, I am using

```
db.First.find().count()  // Show total number of records from First
db.Second.find().count()   // Show total number of records from Second
db.Third.find().count()    // Show total number of records from Third
```

And add all results to get total number of records.

How can i get total number of records from all collections by using single query ?

OR

What is the best way ?

Comment: A single query? You cannot, and basically because "they are separate collections" and MongoDB only ever acts on one collection at a time. You could do something silly with `$facet`, but those are "forced counts" rather than "cursor counts", and the latter is more efficient. So it would be far better and far more scalable to simply iterate the list of collections and obtain the counts. Which will actually get pulled from the cached collection stats rather than by counting every document.

Answer (score 4):

It will provide all documents count in db including system.js documents

```js
db.stats().objects;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can write your own function in @mongodb to count all documents

```js
var collections = db.getCollectionNames();
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
  count += db.getCollection(collections[i]).count();
}
```

Comment: i just want to do this by query at mongo shell, by using mongo query only

Comment: @SNTiwari now it does